# Javascript - How to make sure processing is finished in a remote module?

Tags: javascript, arrays, module, callback, pass-by-reference

I call `called.js` which processes a given array. It takes an unknown length of time to complete. I want to make sure processing is complete before I continue the main sequence in `called.js`.

How do I ensure processing is complete before my main module continues execution?

caller.js

```
//caller.js
var called = require('./called.js');
var inst = new called();
var ary = [1, 2, 3];

console.log('caller before',ary);
inst.process(ary);
console.log('caller after',ary);
//do other stuff with the modified array
```

called.js

```js
//called.js
module.exports = function () {
    var array = [];
    var a = 'a';
    var b = 'b';

    return {
        process: (arr)=> {
          array=arr;
          longtime();
        }
    };

    function longtime(){
        {para_a: a, para_b: b},
        function(err, response) {
              //process the response and update the array
              //takes an unknown time to complete,
              //and the number of elements to be updated are unknown also
        });
    }
};
```

**The Fix**

caller2.js

```js
var called = require('./called.js');
var inst = new called();
var ary = [0, 1, 2];

console.log('caller before',ary);
inst.process(ary, do_work);

function do_work(){
  console.log('processing finished');
  console.log('caller after',ary);
}
```

called2.js

```js
module.exports = function () {
var array = [];

return {
    process: (arr, callback)=> {
      array=arr;
      console.log('process calling longtime');
      longtime(array, function (response){
        console.log('process got callback:',response);
        callback();
      });
    }
  };
};

function longtime (ar, callback){
    setTimeout(function(){ //this simulates a slow API call
      ar.push(3);
      var str = 'array now '+ar.length;
      callback(str);
      }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your `longtime` function. What does it really look like?

Comment: Have you tried using callbacks or promises?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I've corrected it. I'm a little wary of using a callback within a callback. Would I just do something like `inst.process(ary, function(resp){//set ready});`?

Comment: No, calling a callback from the callback is exactly what you should do. Or just pass the callback you are receiving as a parameter directly to `longtime`. Yes, the `inst.process` call would look like that - in place of the `// set ready` you'd have the `console.log('caller after',ary);`.

Comment: All the "other stuff" that depends on the modified array needs to go into the callback.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I used `caller2.js` above and it works nicely. Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback (like bergi told):

Add a function to your normal js:

```
function loaded(){
alert("loaded");
}
```

Add the end of the loaded js insert:

```
loaded();
```

Comment: This is simpler but how does `loaded()` know how to find `function loaded()` in the other module?

Comment: @Steve Taylor: i dont know your environment but normally, all functions are part of the global window object and can call each others easily